# How to display Bootstrap modal in Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, electron, bootstrap-modal

Trying to display Bootstrap Modal in electron.

### I have installed jquery and bootstrap modules.
Then wrote following code in .js file.

```
const $ = require('jquery');
require('bootstrap');

$(document).ready(() => {
  $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

---

### Of course, there is Div tag with id=myModal in .html file.
However, when running, the following error is displayed.

```
$(...).modal is not a function.
```

---

What is the reason and how to implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share me your full code to check on my local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try please your app with this code

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)
```

I met Bootstrap modal issue in ElectronJS in before.
It was work well with this code.

Comment: Thanks, it is working well on my side.